# Cannot read property 'collection' of undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb

**Erro:**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'collection' of undefined
    at Object.findAll (/Users/filipealves/node/crud/db.js:7:17)
    at /Users/filipealves/node/crud/routes/index.js:6:13
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/filipealves/node/crud/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Users/filipealves/node/crud/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/Users/filipealves/node/crud/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/filipealves/node/crud/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /Users/filipealves/node/crud/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/Users/filipealves/node/crud/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/Users/filipealves/node/crud/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at Function.handle (/Users/filipealves/node/crud/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:174:3)
```

Código:

```js
const mongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
mongoClient.connect('mongodb:/localhost:27017/workshop')
.then(conn => global.conn = conn.db('workshop'))
.catch(err => console.log(err));

function findAll(callback) {
    global.conn.collection('customers').find({}).toArray(callback);
};

module.exports = {findAll};
```

Comment: Ola Felipe, bem vindo ao StackOverflow PT. Para ter uma melhor resposta da comunidade seria bom se você explicasse mais sobre o seu problema e desse um Titulo a pergunta em portugues

Comment: Tente especificar melhor qual o seu problema, o que está tentando fazer e o que nºao está conseguindo. Mude o título da sua pergunta para português também. Não cole aqui o erro esperando que alguém venha e resolva. Edite a sua pergunta para que possamos comrpeender melhor.

Comment: Filipe a principio seu erro ocorre pois o seu objeto global.conn está indefinido, é possível que isso tenha ocorrido em decorrência do método de conexão ser assíncrono.

Comment: O erro quer dizer que `global.conn === undefined`, posso estar enganado mas, acredito que o problema esteja em passar o nome do banco pela url em `mongoClient.connect('mongodb:/localhost:27017/workshop')` e depois tentar selecionar um banco em `conn.db('workshop')`. Seria como estisse tentando acessar o banco de dados de outro banco de dados. Mas não tenho certeza. Tente mudar `global.conn = conn.db('workshop')` para `global.conn = conn`